# How to remove Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'm trying to remove Eclipse from my Mac Book Pro OSX. Looking on internet (and also here) I found this code to put in the terminal but it doesn't work

~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.eclipse.plist and ~/Library/Saved Application State/org.eclipse.eclipse.savedState

I put it in the bin and try to remove it completely but the computer says "adb is using". Eclipse is in the folder "adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321". How can I do it?

Comment: Sounds like Eclipse is still running.  Shut it down and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove eclipse folder for now and reboot your mac. You can remove other files late for it might also get clear with other 3rd party disk cleaning app.

Comment: Ok, wait. I remove eclipse, than I have to reboot and Mac. And after?

Comment: or just worry about it. It won't harm you.